# Start Activity while Countdown is running

Tags: java, android, android-activity, google-cloud-messaging, countdowntimer

I have a problem with my Android app at the moment. I use the Google Client Message Service to send messages to my Android App. If the user opens the app, he starts on the `HomeActivity`.

When the user now receives my message from the server and press on the push message, the app starts a new intent with the `AlertActivity`.

At this point, I pass the time (saved in the message) with `putExtra` to the new activity, where i use it for a `CownDownTimer`. Till this point everything is ok and the countdown works perfect.

The problem is now, when the user minimizes the app and open it again.
At this Point the user is not redirected to my `AlertActivity` again but to my `HomeActivity`.

After the `CountDownTimer` Ends the `AlertSound` is played, but he can't cancel it, because he can't show the activity again.

How can I redirect the User to the `AlertActivity` if he starts the app while the `CountDown` is running?

**My AlertActivity**

```
package com.prgguru.example;

public class AlertActivity extends Activity {

    String str;
    Boolean running;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alert);

        final TextView txttime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtalert);
        str = getIntent().getStringExtra("msg");
        Integer time = Integer.parseInt(str);

        time = time; //*60000;

        txttime.setText(time+"");

        CountDownTimer Count = new CountDownTimer(time, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                running = true;
                txttime.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) -
                                TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
                //txttime.setText(""+millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                txttime.setText("Finished");

                final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.alarm);
                mp.start();
            }
        };

        Count.start();
    }

    public boolean getRunning(){
        return false;
    }
}
```

**GCMIntentService**

```
public class GCMIntentService extends IntentService {
    // Sets an ID for the notification, so it can be updated
    public static final int notifyID = 9001;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
                        + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification(extras.get(ApplicationConstants.MSG_KEY)+"");
            }
        }
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, AlertActivity.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra("msg", msg);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder;
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

            mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("Alert")
                    .setContentText("You've received new message.")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            // Set pending intent
            mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

            // Set Vibrate, Sound and Light
            int defaults = 0;
            //defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
            //defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            // defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

            Notification notification = mNotifyBuilder.build();

            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.alarm);
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

            mNotifyBuilder.setDefaults(defaults);
            // Set the content for Notification
            mNotifyBuilder.setContentText("New message from Server");
            // Set autocancel
            mNotifyBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            // Post a notification
            mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, notification);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why dont you count down in service, and then you can handle it from any other activity